# 1:1 relation wrong ID taken

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have two classes which are connected (but unfortunately not via foreign keys):

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }
}
public class Status
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

In this case only the Status table has a "reference" to an Order. One Status belongs to one Order.

How do I tell the DbModelBuilder that the foreign key is `OrderId` and not `Id`?

```
public static void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
        .HasOptional(a => a.Status)
        .WithRequired(x => x.Order)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}
```

When I include the `Status` in my `Order` it will get the Status with the same `Id` as the `Order` has.

Comment: I'm a bit confused.. you first say they're not connected via foreign keys, and then you want to pick the correct foreign key? If you're open to attributes, you can write `[ForeignKey("Order")]` on the `OrderId` property

Comment: We are migrating our customer's old software to a web app. ~20ys ago they used MS Access to create their ERP software and then they somehow migrated that schema to a SQLSRV database, meaning they don't use referential integrity. We use the naming conventions to resolve those objects with "foreign keys". Like OrderId => Order.

Comment: Alright - makes sense. In regards to your comment on the presented answer, it shouldn't matter whether or not there are *actually* foreign keys in the database. If you do not enable migrations, EF should properly generate the select with OrderID. What error do you get when you say it doesn't work?

Comment: This is what I'm getting:  Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Status_Order_Source' in relationship 'Status_Order'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

Comment: You need to also add `[Key]` on both entities' `Id` Property.

Comment: We have it through our ```EntityBase``` class. We just override the ID property to attach the ```ColumnAttribute```.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that - you can't access the Id property? In any case, you can add `.HasKey(o => o.Id)` before your `HasOptional`

Comment: ID property has the ```[Key]``` Attribute through its base class. We just override it to attach a ```[Column]``` attribute as the column has some Prefix and sometimes is not just called "Id".
Our problem is that ```Order``` has an ID of 2014. The according ```Status``` has an ID of 2015 but EF thinks that the ID has to be the same. So Order.Id = 2014 and Status.Id = 2014.

Comment: According to fluent api the relation is `Order 1 - 1..0 Status`.

Comment: Why do you need `Id` for `Status`? If you have `1-1..0` relation the `Status` is defined by `OrderId`, isn't it?

Comment: Well first of all the ```Id``` is defined in our base class for entities that's why it's necessary. Also it is not directly a 1/0..1 relation, in theory there can be multiple ```Status``` rows for one ```Order```. To have a 1/0..1 relation we would need a reference on the ```Order``` side.

Answer (score 0):

Apply `[ForeignKey("Order")]` on `OrderId` property which will make it foreign key for Order entity as shown below.

```
public class Status
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Order")]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, as we don't use one single Foreign Key database-wise. (not our fault, customer was using MS Access before they exportet the db schema to SQLSRV)

Comment: This one:  Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Status_Order_Source' in relationship 'Status_Order'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.